# is it possible to colors the prompt for (reverse-i-search) context menu?

Tags: bash, command-line, colors

I am using fedora 25 but I think this is a general behavior on unix system.

When I `ctrl+r` in a command-line environment I can start to type in and anything I type will get to be matched backward in the invoked command history of the current user. This helps a lot to rapidly find a command and not type it again.

I like to optimize when it comes to my environment, but sometimes when I am fast I found the prompt a bit confusing because everything is white, for instance if I type `find` during the reverse-i-search, the prompt will output something like that,

```
(reverse-i-search)`find': find . -type f -name '*.h'
```

Is there a way to color the part before `:` ?

Comment: What shell are you using? bash, zsh, etc.?

Comment: @Abdul I am using bash

Comment: If you remember what you are looking for, you can do something like `history | grep 'pattern'`  and then type a `!nnn`, where nnn is the command number listed by history. If you still want color, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909942/color-the-linux-command-output. There's also `grcat` https://superuser.com/questions/602294/is-there-colorizer-utility-that-can-take-command-output-and-colorize-it-accordin . And if you want an automagical tool for it, you can try `history | fzf` https://github.com/junegunn/fzf . None of these uses `Ctrl-R`, so it's not posted as an answer.

Comment: Hey @Joe, `fzf` sets up a `Ctrl-R` binding for the shell when you run it's install script, effectively replacing the built in `reverse-i-search`. It colors the search prompt in the exact way OP wanted, so threre's that ;)

Answer (score 0):

As https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352377 suggests, you will have to change source code to do this.  Current versions of Bash (up to and including recently released 5.0) can color only filename completion suggestions; i-search always outputs plain text.